# Compactness of Gaussian Random Field

Tags: compactness

When watching a video on youtube, an instructor says that Gaussian Random Field (GRF) is not compact.
I understand that in GRF, we draw sample from function $u(x)$ from, in the case of zero mean
$$\mathcal{N} \sim (0, K), \quad K_{i,j} = \exp{\big[-||x_{i}-x_{j}||^{2}/l^{2}\big]},$$
with length paramater $l$.
I also know that to be compact, it needs to be bounded and closed.
I can see that it is bounded in the domain of $x$, let’s say $x \in [0,1]$, but how can we say about the closed property and conclude that it is not compact?

Comment: I think I understand it. Gaussian distribution has infinity long tail and thus it is not bounded although the probability of drawing items in the tail is super low.